# Facebook embedded video not playing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, video-streaming

I'm facing problem with facebook video embedded on my post. My client wanted me to follow this method: https://medium.com/@BenBillups/facebook-video-embeds-that-actually-work-57037f8cdcf3

I've done all of the part except PHP code because that wasn't required by my client. Now what is happening. When page loads a play button appear to start video. On click it work just fine. It plays the video but only on desktops. The click event triggers on mobiles and tablets. But it doesn't start the video.
Please take a look at  https://candylish.com/mix-and-match-swirl-cookies/ and also check in mobile. You'll see the difference. 
In short, you've to click twice in mobile to start video.
Please help me sort this out.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply dealing with mobile browser's general reluctance to start playing video, when they can't determine it was directly connected to a user interaction (and therefor likely willingly triggered by the user.)

```
//Autoplay
FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    if (msg.type === 'video') {
        msg.instance.play();
    }
});
```

This code waits for one of the SDK's events to fire and then tries to call the play method, introducing exactly the kind of asynchronism/detachment that gets this blocked, because techniques like that are often used in a malicious way.

> In short, you've to click twice in mobile to start video.

That second click is *"a whole different animal"* altogether ... it happens on the *native* play button of the (now) embedded social plugin. The other script is not involved at all any more at this point, and this click is a direct user interaction that triggers the video to play, so it is allowed to work. This isn't nested into anything asynchronous or callbacks, it is straight up *click => trigger play.*

I don't think you will find any example using this technique where this will work differently.

Mobile browsers are more gracious when it comes to autoplay-on-page-load(!) videos, if those videos do not contain an audio track or are embedded to be muted by default. I don't think Facebook offers the latter as an option for mobile to begin with (the `data-autoplay` attribute does that for desktop, but is documented to not work on mobile) - so at most you could try with a Facebook video that is silent to begin with; but apart from that I'm not sure this restriction resp. when it actually gets lifted even applies here, it's probably not going to fulfill your client's requirement either.

---

*I started typing this as a comment, but besides that it has gotten a little longer now, in this case I think **it can't be done** actually simply **is** the answer, even if it might not be a satisfying one.*